# Nesting of Methods Compilation Error?

Tags: java, class, methods, compiler-errors, java.util.scanner

I am writing a java program to compare two numbers using nesting methods but receiving the error`

```
class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter First Number");
        int X = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Second Number");
        int y = s.nextInt();
        Nesting nest = new Nesting(int, int);
        nest.disp();
    }
}

class Nesting {

    int m, n;

    Nesting(int X, int y) {
        m = X;
        n = y;
    }

    int largest() {
        if (m > n) {
            return m;
        } else {
            return n;
        }
    }

    void disp() {
        int ans = largest();
        System.out.println("My Result is " + ans);
    }
}
```

While compiling receiving the following error

```
Line: 11
'.class' expected

Line: 11
'.class' expected
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a method or constructor, you should not pass the type, instead you have to pass the values, you have to change :

```
Nesting nest = new Nesting(int, int);
```

To this :

```
Nesting nest = new Nesting(X, y);
```

Comment: Its a Constructor  is it or a method. ?

Comment: yes it is a constructor, the same thing @aryan you should not pass the type, you have to pass the values :)

Comment: Nesting nest = new Nesting(int X, int y);
Does  this is  valid ?

Comment: no no @aryan it is not valid why you want to use the type ?

Comment: I have seen such types of method using in paramterized constructor and was following the same here.

Comment: where you see this, can you share the link?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DigTjJ4t98k&t=199s&index=32&list=PLiOa6ike4WAHljIOitb3vR0nXQgneUedR   ,  you can watch from 3.15

Comment: it seems that you don't follow your teacher correctly read and watch the video again so you will understand more @aryan

Comment: While going through it again i found  here i am not using  a parametrized constructor